# BASH autocomplete blank spaces until next line with value

Tags: bash, replace, spaces

im needing help:
I have a file with an output like this:

```
001 value  
    value  
045 value  
    value  
    value  
068 value     
098 value  
    value
```

I need a command to get an output like this:

```
001 value
001 value
045 value
045 value
045 value
068 value
098 value
098 value
```

Comment: the formatting in the question is not correct. They are separated lines...like:
"001    value"
"          value"

Comment: Sorry, im new with this website and i dont know how to format the lines. I think that now is Ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough with `awk`:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{prefix=$1;$1=""}{sub(/^ +/,"");print prefix,$0}' test.in
```

This works with any prefix starting with a digit.

---

Raw bash string manipulation. More understandable than `sed`, but also hardcodes 3-character, not necessarily numeric, prefixes.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "${line:0:3}" != "   " ]]; then
        prefix="${line:0:3}"
    fi
    printf '%s%s\n' "$prefix" "${line:3}"
done < test.in
```

---

This can also be done with `sed`, though it's a little more intricate than the usual `sed` commands. It assumes 3-digit prefixes.
`-E` is for BSD `sed`; it should be replaced with `-r` if you're using GNU `sed`.

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]{3} /{h
s/(...).*/\1/
x
n
}
G
s/...(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/
' file.txt
```